# Un-difference the forecasted values?

Tags: r, difference, forecasting, inverse

I'm forecasting 12 periods of closing stock prices (`h=12`) using differenced data `diff()`, and here is the forecast that I obtain (in differenced values):

```
2.888385
1.1857476
-21.3611575
-0.7809216
-0.5733661
19.5797974
-20.8540668
19.5703453
-20.8459073
-0.63805
-0.6380927
```

How would you go back to find the corresponding "un-differenced" closing stock prices? Knowing that the value of my last observed stock price (at `h=0`) was `152.00`? I'm trying to use `diffinv()` but can't seem to obtain what I am looking for.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your forecasts are in `x` and original value in `h0`, you could do `h0 + cumsum(x)`